# Should I use default(Foo), Foo.Empty, or null?

Tags: c#, constructor, conventions

So C# now allows you to use `default(Foo)` to get a recognized "not filled in yet"/empty instance of a class -- I'm not sure if it is exactly the same as `new Foo()` or not.  Many library classes also implement a `Foo.Empty` property, which returns a similar instance.  And of course any reference type can point to `null`.  So really, what's the difference?  When is one right or wrong?  What's more consistent, or performs better?  What tests should I use when checking if an object is conceptually "not ready for prime time"?  Not everybody has `Foo.IsNullOrEmpty()`.

Comment: What is Foo? Each of the types have different default values!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`default(Foo)` will return null when `Foo` is a class type, zero where `Foo` is a value type (such as int), and an instance of `Foo` with all fields initialized to *their* respective `default()` values where `Foo` is a struct. It was added to the language so that generics could support both value and reference types - more [info at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d.aspx)

Use `default(Foo)` when you're testing a T in the context of `SomeClass<T>` or `MyMethod<T>` and you don't know whether T will be value type, a class type or a struct.

Otherwise, null should mean "unknown", and empty should mean "I know this is empty". Use the Foo.Empty pattern if you genuinely need an empty - but non-null - instance of your class; e.g. `String.Empty` as an alternative to `""` if you need to initialize some variable to the empty string.

Use null if you know you're working with reference types (classes), there's no generics involved, and you're explicitly testing for uninitialized references.

Answer (score 2):

`default(Foo)` works for both value types and reference types.  `New Foo(), null` and `Foo.Empty()` do not.  This makes it a good choice for use with generic types, for example, when you may not know which you're dealing with.  But in most reference-type cases, `null` is probably good enough.

Answer (score 2):

When you know the actual type involved, or if you've got a type parameter constrained with ": class" it's simplest to use the known value (null, 0 etc).

When you've just got a type parameter which is unconstrained or constrained other than to be a reference type, you need to use default(T).